# Calculating a total in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble trying to calculate a running total from within a CASE statement.
I have two tables `@report` and `@question` and two variables `@countCurrent` and `@countSuggested`.

Based off the numbers in the `@report` table compared against either a static value or a value from the `@question` table I need to increment either `@countCurrent` or `@countSuggested`.

Here is what I have so far but instead of getting some combination of 5 in either column, I am only getting 0/1. I think it is part of the JOIN but I can't see what.

```
declare @MinSuccessRate float,
        @countCurrent int,
        @countSuggested int

declare @report table
(
    intID   int identity(1,1),
    intReportID int,
    intParticipantID int,
    acceptable float,
    optimum float
)
insert @report
    select 1,1,.25,.75 union all
    select 1,2,.45,.75 union all
    select 1,3,.35,.75 union all
    select 1,4,.55,.75 union all
    select 1,5,.65,.75

declare @question table
(
    intID   int identity(1,1),
    intParticipantID    int,
    answer  float
)

insert @question
select 1,35 union all
select 1,55 union all
select 1,65 union all
select 1,75 union all
select 1,85

SET @MinSuccessRate=0.75
SET @countCurrent=0
SET @countSuggested=0

UPDATE @report
SET @countCurrent= 
    CASE WHEN acceptable>=@MinSuccessRate 
        THEN @countCurrent+1 
        ELSE 0 
        END,
    @countSuggested=
    CASE WHEN optimum*100 >=q.answer 
        THEN @countSuggested+1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
FROM @report pr 
    INNER JOIN @question q 
    ON pr.intParticipantID=q.intParticipantID
WHERE pr.intReportID=1

select @countCurrent [Current],@countSuggested [Suggested]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complicated SQL query for a running total column.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814054/complicated-sql-query-for-a-running-total-column)

Comment: Why do you call it running total? It's a plain total, unless there is something you or me are missing.

Comment: No, you're probably correct that its not the best title going but fortunately it has been resolved below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multiple table `UPDATE`, each target record can be updated at most once (regardless of how many times is it returned by the join).

However, you don't need `UPDATE` here at all:

```
SELECT  @countCurrent =
        SUM
        (
        CASE
        WHEN acceptable >= @MinSuccessRate 
        THEN
                1
        ELSE
                0
        END
        ),
        @countSuggested =
        SUM
        (
        CASE
        WHEN optimum * 100 >= q.answer 
        THEN
                1
        ELSE
                0
        END
        )
FROM    @report pr 
JOIN    @question q 
ON      q.intParticipantID = pr.intParticipantID
WHERE   pr.intReportID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check this http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-running-totals.html